# Hoe to disable future dates in android

Tags: android, datepicker

I want to `disable future dates` and I used  the code below,

```
mDlgPic.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
```

But whenever I select future dates it's get selected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: your code is fine what you are talking about is the bug we find in android lollipop 5.0.1 that is resolved in next version. @Aditya

Comment: currently I am running on lollipop 5.0.2 and its still selecting future dates/

Comment: you have to check in 5.1.+

Comment: But Whenever I am Running this on 6.0 its working fine

Comment: yes it will not work in 5.0.+

Comment: so how can I solve it.

Comment: it is bug from android so you can do nothing but still you want to resolve you have to check date programatically if it greater than current date remove it from your view or add validation.

Comment: Its not working so how can I solve this.

Comment: Sir I want to validate with current date programatically how should I proceed further,

Answer (score 0):

I also face this issue and It seems bug in `5.0.+`. you will not find this bug in and after `5.1`

you have to programatically manage for `5.0.+` to resolve your issue like check if your  date is not bigger than current date.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score -1):

After Declaring Listener on **DatePicker** use the

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getApplicationContext(), date, Calendar.YEAR, Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);  //date is dateSetListener as per your code in question 
datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis());
```